# QNAP, Hyper-V, unstable windows

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, qnap

I have problem with extremely unstable WS 2012.

I'm using physical server connected with HP switch with 2 ports set by NIC and configured as swithc independet (LACP didn't work).

my QNAP is also connected with two ports as a trunk to that HP switch, but set as LACP.

I'm connecting phyiscal server with QNAP via iSCI. On physical server I have DC (with DHCP + DNS) and a Hyper-V for virtual machines. On Hyper-V I have 2 debians and 6x WS 2012 DC, after installing WS I did backup. The problem is, that those WS are extremely unstable. They are running into blue screen 1/2 times a week, and the only thing I can do is format them. I can't even import that machine from backup.

Few days ago I couldn't even install WS, it came to 80% and bsod so I had to format over and over.

Funniest thing. Both Linux has 25+ days uptime and they are working perfectly, but I can't deal with MS.

Any ideas why they are behaving like that?

P.S.When MS die, errors says that it couldn't connect with QNAP (where it's xvhd was), But they never die all together. Just randomly. One die, while the other 5 is working fine, and in the next day another die.

Best regards.

Comment: What model of QNAP?  Is this in a business, and is this a new architecture for you (Hyper-V, QNAP, iSCSI)?

Comment: Yes exactly, model Is QNAP 12-Bay TurboNAS TS-EC1280U-RP. I found that it is certifed for WS 2012 and 2012 R2, I'm using 2012 R2 and 2012 DataCenter, but I got bsods on both, except Linuxes.
I'm using ISO files, because I don't have DVD drive, and I'm using two different images (one for 2012, and second for 2012 Datacenter).

I have 3 LUNs on that QNAP and I noticed, that those Linuxes are on different LUN, I will try install a new windows using that LUN (maybe it could help?).

Answer (score 2):

Linux and Windows machines have different disk timeouts. 
In a nutshell - Debian tolerates certain storage timeouts which Windows Machine does not survive. 
The easiest way to diagnose if this is the case would be migrating one of the Windows boxes to Hyper-V host's local storage and monitoring its stability.

Another issue may be mixing teaming and iSCSI. I'd suggest to do a latency comparison between LACP connection and a Multipath connection to the same QNAP LUN. For correct iSCSI multipathing your 2 NIC ports need to be on 2 different subnets. You also need to have MPIO feature installed on the initiator side, as well as enable MPIO support for iSCSI devices (Start->MPIO->Discover Multi-Paths)-> Enable MPIO support for iSCSI  devices checkbox(requires reboot)

Comment: I have a VM installed on my physical server and it works great.

and btw, today we had a blackout for about 7 hours in night, qnap died same as everything else and I dont have permits I guess for about 300GB of VM data. It exists, because I can see the space used, but I can't connect to VM's. I have no access to Linuxes, and all WS 2012 except 1.